# SQLite - too many levels of trigger recursion

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sqlite3, sqlite-studio

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo, quando tento fazer uma inserção no SQLite.

> Error while executing SQL query on database 'BDTESTE': too many levels of trigger recursion

Criação da tabela

```
CREATE TABLE INSTANCES (
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
DESCRIPTION text,
CONFIG_TXT text,
EXTRA_TXT text,
CREATED varchar(50) NULL,
MODIFIED varchar(50) NULL
);
```

Criação da Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTANCE_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON INSTANCES
BEGIN
UPDATE INSTANCES SET CREATED = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```

Criação da Trigger - Update

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTANCE_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON INSTANCES
BEGIN
UPDATE INSTANCES SET MODIFIED = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE ID = OLD.ID;
END;
```

Inserção

```
INSERT INTO INSTANCES (NAME, DESCRIPTION, CONFIG_TXT, EXTRA_TXT)
VALUES
('app02', 'Intancia de teste Windows', 'blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah', '');
```

Comment: Não tem nenhuma trigger de update?

Comment: Tem sim @JeffersonQuesado, atualizei a publicação

Comment: Interessante, eu criei [uma trigger com a mesma estrutura que a sua](https://github.com/TotalCross/tcrest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tc/rest/ui/TCRestMenu.java#L247) e funciona perfeitamente...

Comment: Ah, então o problema está aí, na trigger de update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na `trigger` de `update`. O `update` gerará o disparo da `trigger`, então você estará condenado a um laço infinito se não tratar corretamente.

Talvez o seguinte funcione (ignora atualizações que não setam informações novas):

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTANCE_UPDATE AFTER UPDATE ON INSTANCES
BEGIN
    UPDATE INSTANCES SET MODIFIED = DATETIME('NOW')
    WHERE ID = OLD.ID AND MODIFIED != DATETIME('NOW');
END;
```

Isso vai evitar que você atualize de modo vacuoso uma linha qualquer.

Outra alternativa seria operar em `views` com `triggers`, depois eu coloco aqui. Exige um tanto a mais de código.

Comment: Alterei como seu exemplo e a inserção funcionou, porém realizei um update e não atualizou o campo "MODIFIED"

Comment: @LucasSouza, oops? Preciso testar mais então...

Comment: Executei este update "UPDATE INSTANCES SET NAME = 'app01' WHERE ID = 2", atualizou o dado porém o campo MODIFIED não.. Depois se conseguir testar e me falar, fico grato...

Comment: @LucasSouza falo sim, espero conseguir testar hoje ainda ainda

Comment: Tranquilo! Fico aguardando!

Comment: Funcionou o update também, só em algumas tabelas que não funciona.. Acho que é pala da IDE, pois ontem não estava funcionando em uma tabela e hoje funcionou.... Obrigado!